# How to avoid plotting the non-exist date in dataframe plot?

Tags: python, plot

Pandas plot plots the non-exist date. How to avoid plotting them? For example, a pandas series is follows. The preferred plot is the one only plotting these 3 points.

```
df = pd.Series(np.array([1, 2, 3]), index=(pd.Timestamp('2004-01-01'),
                                           pd.Timestamp('2004-01-02'),
                                           pd.Timestamp('2005-01-01')))
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the dates as datetime types, convert them to string.

Comment: You could also bin the variables together, so putting 2004 into a single bin to avoid this issue. This will always be the case when you use datetime as it is a continuous variable

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to plot only three dots?